# Jquery: mouseover event on image map area

Tags: jquery, image, dictionary, area

I'm trying to do actions on mouseover of an image map area.  Here is my HTML:

```
<img src="img/denisanddavid-bkgd.jpg" alt="Denis and David - web development and solution" width="1024" height="1299" border="0" usemap="#bkgdMap" id="bkgd" />
    <map name="bkgdMap" id="bkgdMap">
         <area shape="rect" coords="12,161,341,379" href="#" alt="qdk" id="qdk" class="mapping" />
         <area shape="rect" coords="347,162,675,379" href="#" alt="gifgif" alt="gifgif" class="mapping" />
    </map>
```

And here is my js:

```
$('.mapping').mouseover(function() {

    alert($(this).attr('id'));

}).mouseout(function(){
    alert('Mouseout....');      
});
```

I don't understand why, but the jquery is only launched for the first area and not the others.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried your code in Safari and it works just as intended. 2 separate areas that give out separate alerts. One is alerting "qdk" and other "undefined", as you don’t have an ID attribute for the second map.

Comment: good catch, I never even looked at the IDs :) Sad thing is, I have burned myself on this before.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using hover?

example from jquery site...

```
$("td").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```